# PHP how to remove and add commas

Tags: php

How can I remove extra commas and add commas for example using PHP

user submitted data

```
stack,,,,,,,,,,,,,,overflow
```

should output.

```
stack, overflow
```

Comment: @Adam Backstrom add comma example stack, overflow

Comment: @Adam Backstrom  stack,,,,,,,,,,,,,,overflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$out = preg_replace("/,+/",", ",$in);
```

Comment: This function will add a space after all commas, even ones that already have a space after them.

Comment: @Peter: the input condition was quite clear on that one: just commas. Replace the regexp with `"/,+\\s*/"` to also reduce whitespace to one space.

Answer (score 1):

`preg_replace('/[,]+/', ',', $string);` should do it... though depending on the nature of the input you may need a more complex expression.

Answer (score 0):

`$str = preg_replace('/,+/' , ',' , $str);`

This will replace each sequence of one or more commas with one comma.